# Build framework with multiple targets

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I have a project, that is divided into few `targets` (`Cocoa Touch Frameworks`). Some of these `targets` depends on others. I would like to create a single `framework` from this, that will contain all the `targets`, so that I can just import this `framework` into new application, and use all the code inside all of my `targets`. How can this be achieved? I have read something about `Umbrella frameworks`, but I couldn't make it work.

This is how the project is divided into targets:

```
 - Observation
 - BackgroundTask
 - Placement
 - ZIPFoundation
 - NetworkOperation   Dependencies - Observation
 - LocationService    Dependencies - Observation, BackgroundTask, Placement
 - World              Dependencies - Observation, LocationService
 - AugmentedReality   Dependencies - Observation, LocationService
 - FindloAR           Dependencies - AugmentedReality, NetworkOperation, World, Placement, Observation, ZIPFoundation
```

And from all this I would like to create a single `universal framework`, named: `FindloFramework` for `iOS`

Could someone guide me on how to do this?

Comment: Create a new target that has all the others as dependencies?

Comment: OK, that is a start, but how do I compile this so that it will be just single .framework file to import? With just this target, I still need to import other dependencies to the new project, as these are not yet included in FindloFramework.framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible on iOS. Umbrella frameworks are Mac only.

I've had conversations with Apple engineers at WWDC about this, and have submitted a bug. My guess is they're trying to minimize the amount of dynamic linking occurring at runtime.

You need to take all your code and put it into a single framework target.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I was sure that I just did something wrong. If this it the case I will probably just release this as a collection of few small frameworks.